# Regarding register configuration being constant across power cycles

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, ethernet, flash, shift-register

[Ethernet Switch - KSZ8775](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/KSZ8775CLX-Integrated-5-Port-10-100-Managed-Ethernet-Switch-DS00002129D.pdf)

Is there a way to make the chip register configuration persistent, across multiple power cycles, so that we don't have to reprogram the chip every time we turn it off and on? I've been looking through the datasheet I can't find an obvious way to program the switch, such that it keeps the register configurations persistently stored, but at this point, I'm not sure if that's possible at all.
So, is there a way to program/configure the chip registers persistently? If so, would I do that?

Comment: Looking over the datasheet I don't see any non-volatile memory that you could utilize. Why is programming on power-up an issue? Just stick a simple MCU on there with a set of instructions to send on power-up.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @InBedded16

Comment: If it was possible it would tell you. It is normal that most chips do not retain their configuration across power cycles.